# How to bind a (UDP) raw socket to interface device

Tags: c, linux, sockets

My goal is to get all (UDP) messages from a single interface device. I work on Ubuntu 20.04, programming in C.

A raw socket seemed to be the best solution, the problem is the binding to the interface seems not to work. I still get what seems like ALL messages from all devices.

```c
//Create raw socket
if ((sock_fd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
    printf ("Cannot create raw socket!\n");
    return -1;
}

//Bind to interface
if ((setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, if_name, strlen(if_name)+1)) < 0) {
    printf ("Failed to bind socket to interface device %s!\n", if_name);
    return -1;
}

while(1){
    memset (buffer, 0, BUF);
    if ((n = recv(sock_fd, buffer, BUF, 0)) < 0){
        printf("No data available!\n");
        continue;
    }
    //Print data frame
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("0x%x ", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

During execution, I get no errors.

Interestingly, I get no messages at all when I change `htons(ETH_P_ALL)` to `IPPROTO_UDP` in the `socket()` command (finally, I want to end up only with UDP messages).

Did I miss something?

EDIT: To better specify my goal: i want all UDP messages on a single interface device for both IPv4 and IPv6 and with multiple src and dst IPs/Ports (so basically a sniffer for UDP messages on that interface).

Comment: I recommend you read [the socket(7) manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), especially the section about `SO_BINDTODEVICE` which will tell you that: "Note that this works only for some socket types, particularly `AF_INET` sockets.  **It is not supported for packet sockets** (use normal `bind(2)` there)." (emphasis mine).

Comment: Are you trying to receive Ethernet frames or IP packets?

Comment: If you only want UDP messages why are you using raw sockets?

Comment: @ Some programmer dude: i tried with AF_INET and it made no difference
@ user253751:  the complete frames would be best
@user207421: because the UDP messages come from a single ECU but with multiple different SRC IPs, SRC Ports, Dst IPs and Dst Ports (some even broad/multicast) and i thought creating so many connections would be more work

Comment: @Serakis One IP packet (actually called a datagram) can be split up into many frames. So are you more interested in the frames or the packets?

Comment: What exactly *is* happening? Blocking in `recv()`, or 'no data available'? If the latter, `recv()` returned -1, so you should have called `perror()` instead of merely printing text of your own devising. NB The `memset()` is pointless.

Comment: Blocking in `rec()`, no error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all UDP packets coming into the system, you'll want to use an `AF_INET` socket, not `AF_PACKET`, and you'll want to set the protocol to `IPPROTO_UDP`:

```
if ((sock_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
    perror("Cannot create raw socket!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Note that you want to use `perror` instead of `printf` when a socket function fails.  This will tell you *why* the call failed.

Also note that this also only receives packets that your system is "supposed to" see, i.e. those where the destination IP is either the interface IP or a broadcast / multicast address.

Comment: The calls are not failing, i just seem to get either none or ALL messages from all interfaces.

So to get all messages on the interface not just the ones supposed for me i need to change what? :/

Comment: @Serakis did you try this answer, did it work?

Comment: On a side note: the claim that this will "*see all UDP packets coming into the system*" is misleading, as creating an `AF_INET` socket will only be able to receive IPv4 packets, but not IPv6 packets. You would need a separate `AF_INET6` socket to receive IPv6 packets, or use an `AF_UNSPEC` socket instead to receive both.

Comment: So i tried the suggestions based on this socket creation:

AF_UNSPEC (with either IPPROTO_UDP and htons(ETH_P_ALL)) got me the error message ": Address family not supported by protocol"
AF_INET with IPPROTO_UDP seems to work but of course only for ipv4 and i need both v4 and v6.
AF_INET with htons(ETH_P_ALL) gets me the error message ": Invalid argument"
AF_INET6 with IPPROTO_UDP creates the socket and binds it to the if device but then doesen't receive any messages
AF_INET6 with htons(ETH_P_ALL) gets me the error message ": Invalid argument"
So none of the solutions is working for now

Comment: Oh and my AF_PACKET with IPPROTO_UDP creates the socket and binds it to device but will receive no messages.
AF_PACKET with htons(ETH_P_ALL) on the other hand seems to get me ALL messages again from all devices.

Comment: @Serakis You may be stuck with filtering in your application.